# Why does this O(n^2) solution work faster than the O(n) solution?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, set, timeit

*edit: Sorry! It seems I had carelessly copy-pasted the same code.*

---

The question:

> Given a list of numbers from 0 to N-1, your job is to find the missing
>   number. Your program should take in a list of integers and return a
>   single integer (the missing number).

i.e. an input of `[0, 1, 3, 4, 5]` should return `2`.

I found two solutions, one I think in O(n), and one in (On^2).

**O(n) Solution**

```
def alt_find_missing(input_list):
    input_sum = sum(input_list)
    range_sum = sum([i for i in range(min(input_list), max(input_list)+1)])
    return range_sum - input_sum
```

**O(n^2) Solution**

```
def find_missing(input_list):
    input_set = set(input_list)
    for i in range(min(input_list), max(input_list)+1):
        if i not in input_set:
            return i
```

However, the O(n^2) solutions runs faster than the O(n) in multiple `timeit` tests:

```
List with 4 elements, using for ... in set (x 1 000 000)
1.1550223514080038
List with 4 elements, using difference of sums (x 1 000 000)
1.391524411772641
List with 100 elements, using for ... in set (x 1 000 000)
8.43574248785071
List with 100 elements, using difference of sums (x 1 000 000)
8.94695660741872
List with 1000 elements, using for ... in set (x 100 000)
8.1138781071155
List with 1000 elements, using difference of sums (x 100 000)
8.383110816298519
```

Why is this?

Comment: I think you got your title backwards.

Comment: Your two functions look identical to me.

Comment: Not sure what the list comp is for when you can do `sum(range(min(input_list), max(input_list)+1))` also, as the problem states that is ranges from `0 to N - 1` you can then just have `sum(range(max(input_list)+1))`

Comment: And in addtion, the sum of numbers up to `n` is `n^2/2 + n/2`.

Comment: as the functions are the same the only thing I can think of is that the second run take advantage of CACHE'd values ... if the case then enlarging the dataset to really large set (not fitting into CACHE) or invalidating the cache with different data before each run will equalize the run-times.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. I think the question is well posed and you put some thought into it, +1 from me. I would like to see your set solution code. And the comment from Klaus D. is great.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  If you're using Python 2 then you should change `range()` to `xrange()`, because `range()` builds a list.  You're also building a list and discarding it (after using it to compute the sum) with your list comprehension.It would help if you gave more details about the O(n^2) example.  You're data set may be small enough that the overhead of some of your operations are ruining the performance of the O(n) solution.  And keep in mind, being O(n) does mean that it will *always* beat an O(n^2) solution, just as things get big it will do better eventually.

Comment: Hi all! Sorry about that duplicate. I've just fixed it, hope it can clear some things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second algorithm is not O(n^2). Set lookups are O(1) and iterating over a set is O(n). So the difference between two algorithms is due to different constant factors.

Here is a short script that shows linear behavior of both functions

```
import timeit
from functools import partial
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def alt_find_missing(input_list):
    input_sum = sum(input_list)
    range_sum = sum([i for i in range(min(input_list), max(input_list)+1)])
    return range_sum - input_sum


def find_missing(input_list):
    input_set = set(input_list)
    for i in range(min(input_list), max(input_list)+1):
        if i not in input_set:
            return i


t1=[]
t2=[]

rng=range(10000,1000000,10000)

for n in rng:
    func1=partial(find_missing,range(n))
    func2=partial(alt_find_missing,range(n))
    t1.append(timeit.timeit(func1,number=5))
    t2.append(timeit.timeit(func2,number=5)) 

plt.plot(rng,t1, label='Find missing')
plt.plot(rng,t2, label='Alt find missing')
plt.ylabel('Execution time')
plt.xlabel('Problem size')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The result looks pretty linear to me :) Certainly there's something peculiar going on at some problem sizes, but nothing to throw results significantly out of linearity zone.

Regards.
[image: Two linear functions]

Comment: Set lookups are O(1) at best and O(n) at worst. One one side you have the set creation n * (O(1)..O(n)) and its access n*(O(1)..O(n)). On the other side you have the n-list and its FOR loop (O(n)). So it can add up to O(n^2) in worst case.

Comment: Yes, I did do some googling beforehand to check the time complexity of set lookups, seems O(n) at worst case: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: O(n) worst case does not make algorithm O(n) the same way as O(n^2) worst case complexity of quicksort does not make it quadratic.
In Python sets are implemented through hash tables so worst time complexity is achieved when all of your hashes collide. Which is rather unlikely.